# Efficient top k words using MultiMap (Google Guava ext lib JAR)

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, guava

Basic algorithm:

1. Open document/huge text file
2. Use `Map` and `List` to separate the words. \$O(K)\$ time complexity (TC) considering \$K\$ distinct words.
3. If the word already exists in the list, increment the count of frequency, else add the new word. Constant TC.
4. Use a `Collection` to sort the list on the basis of frequency of usage. \$n*log(n)\$ TC.
5. Print the list, `Entry.getKey` (max count word), and its `Entry.getValue` (max count).

Now, I tried to use `Multimap` before sorting so that I can group same frequency count words. This will drastically decrease the sorting complexity as the number of elements to compare will decrease.

Is it efficient enough or are there other ways to make it more efficient?

```
//Below code works fine (Please include lib files as per your IDE setting)
    package Topk;
    //---import necessary lib---
    class Words
    {
        int count=1;
        String word;
        Words(int count, String word)
        {
            this.count = count;
            this.word = word;
        }
    }

    public class TopK 
    {
        public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException
        {
            int Tcount = 0;
            Map<String,Integer> map = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt"));
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                String[] words = line.split("\\W");
                for(String word:words)
                {
                    word = word.toLowerCase();
                    Tcount++;
                    if(word.equals(""))
                        continue;
                    insert(word,map);
                }
            }               
            Multimap<Integer, String> mm = ArrayListMultimap.create();
            Iterator<String> itr = map.keySet().iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext())
            {
                String key = (String) itr.next();
                int tempi = map.get(key);
                String temps = key;
                mm.put(tempi,temps);
            }

            Map<String,Integer> fmap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
            Set<Integer> keys = mm.keySet();
            for(int i : keys)
            {
                int value = i;
                String temps = (mm.get(i).toString());
                fmap.put(temps,value);
            }

            List<Entry<String, Integer>> wordList =  sorting(fmap);
            display(wordList,Tcount);
            br.close();
        }

        // INSERTING INTO THE MAP////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        private static void insert(String word, Map<String, Integer> map) 
        {
            if(map.containsKey(word))
            {
                int temp = map.get(word);
                temp++;
                map.put(word, temp);
            }
            else
                map.put(word, 1);
        }

        // SORTING METHOD/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        private static List<Entry<String, Integer>> sorting(Map<String, Integer> fmap) 
        {
            Set<Entry<String, Integer>> wordSet = fmap.entrySet();
            List<Entry<String, Integer>> wordList = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(wordSet);

            Collections.sort(
                                wordList, 
                                new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>()
                                {
                                    public int compare( Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2 )
                                    {
                                        return (o2.getValue()).compareTo( o1.getValue() );
                                    }
                                }
                            );      
            return wordList;
        }

        // DISPLAY METHOD/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        private static void display(List<Entry<String, Integer>> wordList, int tcount) 
        {
            // Display all the words & count ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry:wordList) // for every word search the frequency
            {
                System.out.println(entry.getValue()+": "+entry.getKey());
            }
            // Top frequently used word --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Entry<String, Integer> max = wordList.get(0);
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Total words : "+tcount);    
            System.out.println("Maximum frueqncy word - "+ max.getKey()+" : "+max.getValue()+" times.");
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to CR! Are you on Java 8?

Comment: Thank you! If you mean Java 8 for coding - yes I have multiple version and if you mean Java 8 chat room - Not yet

Comment: Yeah, I'm referring to Java 8 for coding... :)

Comment: Yes, I wrote this code in "Java 8 Update 45", Did you asked coz of Guava lib? its compatible with 7 also

Comment: I asked because some of the statements you wrote can be implemented in a more concise way using Java 8...

Comment: Correct, Sorry for such statements. I came from background of C and kernel/Unix development. I will surely make changes to make it compatible and efficient with Java 8.

Comment: No worries, we are all here to learn and help! :)

Comment: Do you find any improved logic in this code to make it more efficient logic?

Comment: To process 10 million lines of text (96MB) it takes 0.79 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Java/Java 8 tips

`Words` is an unused class, and even if it is in used, class naming convention recommends the singular form rather than the plural. This is because you will have a `Word` instance or many `Word` instances, but a `Words` instance doesn't sound as right. The only pluralized class names that I can recall off-hand are for utilities classes, i.e. those that only provide a bunch of `static` methods.

Since Java 7, the recommended approach for reading from a `Reader` source is [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), e.g.

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In Java 8, there is an even more convenient way of *specifying* how you want to read and process lines from a text file, which I will explain below...

### Your Guava-based approach

> 1. Read each `line` and split into `words`.
> 2. Store a running count as the variable `Tcount`.
> 3. For each non-empty `word` in `words`, insert the lowercase form into a `map`.
>
>    - Insertion is based on checking if `word` exists in the `map`. If it does, increment the counter, else add `word => 1` to the `map`.
> 4. Create a `Multimap`, `mm`.
> 5. Loop through the keys of `map` to add the count-per-word pairing to `mm`.
> 6. Create another `HashMap`, `fmap`.
> 7. Loop through `mm` to add the `toString()` representation of each value as the key for `fmap`, with the key being the value for `fmap`.
> 8. Sort `fmap` into a `List<Entry<String, Integer>>` data structure.
>
>    - This is done by wrapping the `entrySet()` into a `List`, and applying `Collections.sort()` on the new `List`.
> 9. Display the result.

- `Tcount` can be better renamed as `totalCount` or `wordCount`, following the `camelCase` naming convention for variables, and the unnecessary need to shorten variable names (unless they are really long).
- Your implementation for step 3, i.e. the `insert()` method, has a simpler implementation in Java 8 using [`Map.merge()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

  ```
  map.merge(word, 1, (a, b) -> a + b);
  ```

  What this means is to either add `word => 1` to the `map` if it does not exist, or use the [`BiFunction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) lambda declaration to add the existing and new (i.e. `1`) values.
- Steps 4 to 7 are... quite lengthy and you can rely on some of Guava's built-in methods to perform the same operations too:

  ```
  Multimap<Integer, String> inverseMap = Multimaps.invertFrom(Multimaps.forMap(map),
                                              ArrayListMultimap.create());
  ```

  - You can use [`Multimaps.forMap(Map)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#forMap(java.util.Map)) to give you a `Multimap` wrapper over the original `Map` so that it can be used as an argument for...
  - [`Multimaps.invertFrom`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#invertFrom(com.google.common.collect.Multimap,%20M)), inverting the `key => value` mapping of a `Multimap` into a resulting `Multimap` instance, which you can declare as `ArrayListMultimap.create()`.
- Step 8 is quite an odd step, partly because I feel you have deconstructed a `Map` semantic as a sorted `List` of `Entry` instances. This definitely can be implemented in the form of a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), which allows you to sort on the keys while giving you additional flexibility of retrieving using `Map`-friendly methods. After sorting the keys, you can simply use the largest key to `get()` from your `Multimap` as your result, instead of having to deal with a `List<Entry>` data structure.
- Putting together, steps 4 to 8 can probably be done as such:

  ```
  private static <K, V extends Comparable<V>> Collection<K> getMaximumByValue(
          Map<K, V> map) {
      Multimap<V, K> inverseMap = Multimaps.invertFrom(Multimaps.forMap(map),
                                              ArrayListMultimap.create());
      return inverseMap.get(Ordering.natural().immutableSortedCopy(inverseMap.keys())
                                      .reverse().get(0));
  }
  ```

### A non-Guava-based approach

With Java 8, one can also learn to apply the new `Stream`-based processing techniques that can simplify most of the explicit looping.

For example, to read a file in as a `Stream` of lines using [`Files.lines(Path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-):

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(path))) {
    // perform further operations on lines, e.g. lines.collect()...
}
```

Processing each line into your `map`, i.e. step 3 above, can be done by:

- [`flapMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-)-ing every line with a replacement of `Stream` of words,

  - The method reference to use here will be [`Pattern::splitAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-).
- [`filter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-)-ing for non-empty `String`s, before performing a
- [`collect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-), [`groupingBy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-), and then [`counting()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--) on the word occurrences:

  ```
  private static final Pattern LINE_SPLIITER = Pattern.compile("\\W");

  private static Map<String, Long> process(Stream<String> lines) {
      return lines.flatMap(LINE_SPLIITER::splitAsStream).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase, Collectors.counting()));
  }
  ```

The equivalent of using a Guava `Multimap` so that the values can be sorted is to apply another form of [`groupingBy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) on the resulting `Map` from above:

```
private static <K, V extends Comparable<V>> Collection<K> getMaximumByValue(
        Map<K, V> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getValue, TreeMap::new,
                            Collectors.mapping(Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())))
            .lastEntry().getValue();
}
```

This time round, we are grouping by using `Entry::getValue` (method reference) as the key, and then *specifying* the use of a `TreeMap` as our backing `Map` implementation. [`Collectors.mapping()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) is finally used to again *specify* how we want to collate duplicate keys together as the new `Map` values.

Now that we have a `TreeMap` instance, we only need to call [`lastEntry()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#lastEntry--) to get our result.

### Putting it all together

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // will be good to validate args[0]
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(args[0])) {
        Map<String, Long> map = process(lines);
        System.out.println("Word count: "
                + map.values().stream().mapToLong(Long::longValue).sum());
        System.out.println(getMaximumByValue(map));
    }
}
```

Quick explanation on getting the word count: Convert the `Stream<Long>` from `map.values().stream()` into a `LongStream` by calling [`mapToLong()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToLong-java.util.function.ToLongFunction-). Then, we can use the [`sum()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#sum--) method to get the count.