# Find the rarest in a map

Tags: java, hash-map, set

> Write a method rarest that accepts a map whose keys are strings and
> whose values are integers as a parameter and returns the integer value
> that occurs the fewest times in the map. If there is a tie, return the
> smaller integer value. If the map is empty, throw an exception.
>
> For example, suppose the map contains mappings from students' names
> (strings) to their ages (integers). Your method would return the least
> frequently occurring age. Consider a map variable m containing the
> following key/value pairs:
>
> {Alyssa=22, Char=25, Dan=25, Jeff=20, Kasey=20, Kim=20, Mogran=25,
> Ryan=25, Stef=22}
>
> Three people are age 20 (Jeff, Kasey, and Kim), two
> people are age 22 (Alyssa and Stef), and four people are age 25 (Char,
> Dan, Mogran, and Ryan).
>
> So a call of rarest(m) returns 22 because only
> two people are that age. If there is a tie (two or more rarest ages
> that occur the same number of times), return the youngest age among
> them. For example, if we added another pair of Kelly=22 to the map
> above, there would now be a tie of three people of age 20 (Jeff,
> Kasey, Kim) and three people of age 22 (Alyssa, Kelly, Stef). So a
> call of rarest(m) would now return 20 because 20 is the smaller of the
> rarest values.

Here is the [link](http://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/problem.jsp?category=Building%20Java%20Programs%2C%203rd%20edition%2FBJP3%20Chapter%2011&problem=bjp3-11-e19-rarest) to the question.

```
public int rarest(Map<String, Integer> m)throws Exception{
    if(m.size() == 0){
      throw new Exception();//throwing an exception as per the question
    }else{
    Integer count = null;
    //Creating a TreeMap to get the lowest age.
    TreeMap<Integer, Integer> t = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> me : m.entrySet()){
        if(t.containsKey(me.getValue())) {
            count = t.get(me.getValue());
            t.put(me.getValue(), count+1);
        }else {
            count = 1;
            t.put(me.getValue(), count);
        }
      }  
        
     //If there is tie I am comparing the frequencies   
     int freq = t.get(t.firstKey());

     TreeSet<Integer> val = new TreeSet<Integer>();

     for(Integer i : t.keySet()){
        if(freq > t.get(i) ){
            freq = t.get(i);
            val.add(i);
        } 
     }
        if(val.size() > 0){    
           return val.first();
        }else{
           return t.firstKey();
        } 
    }
}
```

It gives the correct results for the given test cases, but I feel there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: Are you on Java 8?

Comment: Is there a better way in Java 8!!. I am yet to learn the new features, but you can go ahead if you have something novel from that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public int rarest(Map<String, Integer> m) throws Exception
```

1. Since this method does not require stateful information other than the method argument, you can mark it as `static`.
2. Is this method expected to throw a [checked `Exception`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html)? If not, you are better off removing the `throws` declaration, as it otherwise forces callers to catch on an `Exception`, which is ambiguously broad.
3. Ok, so you want to throw *some kind* of `Exception` when the method argument is empty (note: `m.isEmpty()` is preferred as it communicates the intent better). If that is the case, you should be throwing an unchecked runtime exception, such as `IllegalArgumentException`. Give a friendly description if required, e.g. `throw new IllegalArgumentException("map cannot be empty")`.
4. Generally, it is better to use longer, descriptive variable names in Java. The only 'exception' since Java 8 seems to be in lambda declarations, but don't take this as the norm... I simply prefer terser variable names in lambda declarations as well.

(*the following part is [heavily inspired](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/101719/27975) from my other answer to a recent, similar question*)

```
if(t.containsKey(me.getValue())) {
    count = t.get(me.getValue());
    t.put(me.getValue(), count+1);
}else {
    count = 1;
    t.put(me.getValue(), count);
}
```

If you happen to be on Java 8, you can use [`Map.merge()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
t.merge(me.getValue(), 1, (a, b) -> a + b);
```

What this means is to either add `me.getValue() => 1` to `t` if it does not exist, or use the [`BiFunction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) lambda declaration to add the existing and new (i.e. `1`) values.

Your current solution for iterating through the ordered keys of `t` is fine, but since you're interested to learn more about the `Stream`-based processing features of Java 8, here goes...

So, you roughly figured you need two steps to get your answer:

1. Count the number of occurrences for each age

   - You can apply a [`groupingBy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) on `m`'s values, using [`Collectors.counting()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--) to populate the *intermediate* map's values:

     ```
     // assume map is the method argument
     Map<Integer, Long> temp = map.entrySet().stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getValue, Collectors.counting()))
     ```
2. Sort by the least values, then by the youngest age

   - From this intermediate map, you can stream the entries, sort by the values using a custom `Comparator` lambda declaration and then return the first entry, i.e. the *rarest*:

     ```
     temp.entrySet().stream()
         .sorted((e1, e2) -> { 
             int v = e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
             return v != 0 ? v : e1.getKey().compareTo(e2.getKey());
         })
         .findFirst().map(Entry::getKey).get().intValue();
     ```

Putting it altogether, you will have a nice, compact `rarest()` method:

```
public static int rarest(Map<String, Integer> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getValue,
                    Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .sorted((e1, e2) -> { 
                int v = e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
                return v != 0 ? v : e1.getKey().compareTo(e2.getKey());
            })
            .findFirst().map(Entry::getKey).get().intValue();
}
```

**edit**: Once again, [@Misha](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/101835/27975)'s answer is a welcome improvement of mine, do take a look at that too!

Comment: What do you mean by stateful information? Is it the info about a particular object state!!

Comment: It's better to use `min` instead of `sorted` + `findFirst`.  Also, you can string together comparators using `thenComparing` instead of writing out that logic by hand

Comment: @JohnDoe nothing in the method implementation relies on class fields, i.e. instantiating the class.

Comment: @Misha thanks for saving the day once again! :) I have updated my answer to point to yours. My mind was clearly borked when I used `.sorted().findFirst()`...

Answer (score 6):

This is more efficient than the accepted answer.  `min` is O(1) memory and O(n) time while `sorted` is O(n) memory and O(n*log(n)) time:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparingLong;
import static java.util.Comparator.comparingInt;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;


Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Long>> byRarity = comparingLong(Map.Entry::getValue);
Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Long>> byAge = comparingInt(Map.Entry::getKey);

int rarest = data.values().stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(x->x, counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .min(byRarity.thenComparing(byAge))
        .get()        // or throw if map is empty
        .getKey();
```